# Fluid simulation not continuous flow

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I've a fluid simulation in which the emission object, an icosphere, is moving upwards quite fast. The problem is that the fluid that is emited form balls instead of a continuous flow. I tried to change the velocity of the fluid, but that just make the balls goes faster...

[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always increase the *Timesteps* in the *Domain* which calculates more data inbetween frames to make it smoother which then applies to all fluid objects in the domain.

Or, if you have different fluid objects in the domain, you might only want to increase the *Sampling Substeps* on the fast moving *Flow* object (the picture shows the default values for *Domain* and *Flow*).

[image: timesteps]

For more details check the Blender Manual:

- [Adaptive Time Steps](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/domain/settings.html?highlight=adaptive%20time%20steps)
- [Sampling Substeps](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/fluid/type/flow.html?highlight=sampling%20substeps)

Comment: That worked, thanks! One question more...what's the difference between the timesteps and the sampling substeps?

Comment: @Artichoke If answer solved your issue consider mark as Accepted so other can see it from main list https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you keep this site organised.

Comment: @vklidu Sorry, I'm new and I'm still figuring out how it works. I'll do that in my next question. Thanks!